# Memory leak on ruby gtk-3

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, gtk3

I'm experiencing a memory leak on ruby 2.3.1 with gtk-3.
On my system (Ubuntu 16-04) the following code consumes approximately 80 MB.
The size of picture.jpg is 289kb.

`require 'gtk3'

```
  def ptest
    i=0
    j=0
    loop {
    i += 1
    j += 1
    exit if j==50
    @image = Gtk::Image.new
    newPixbuf = GdkPixbuf::Pixbuf.new(:file => "picture.jpg")
    @image.pixbuf = newPixbuf
    @image.clear
    @image=nil
    if i == 10
      p "GC"
      GC.start
      i = 0
    end
    }
  end

  ptest`
```

According https://sourceforge.net/p/ruby-gnome2/mailman/message/8659687/ this shouldn't happen. What can I do to release the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there has been a bug in my Ruby gdk3-Gem. A gem update solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into Ruby but know some bits of Gtk+.
In C, where you must deal with memory allocations by yourself, you need to unref the pixbuf.

From [GtkImage Documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-new-from-pixbuf):

> The GtkImage does not assume a reference to the pixbuf; you still need to unref it if you own references.

So, most probably, if Ruby doesn't implement ARC (Automatic Reference Counting on GObjects), you must do something like `newPixbuf.unref` (not sure about Ruby syntax) right after `@image.pixbuf = newPixbuf`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was my first thought as well but unfortunatley there is no unref-method in ruby for Pixbuf-objects. So I thought the ruby garbage collector GC should do the job, but it doesn't.

Comment: unref method is not a Pixbuf method but a GObject method and Pixbuf inherits from GObject. Just saw that GC it's a Garbage Collector but maybe gobject-introspection isn't that stable within Ruby. I'm trying to read a bit on Ruby-Gtk+ and in fact there are some issues with this ref/unref / reference counting method of GLib

Comment: Could you try a solution almost similar to the one on the link you supplied but with a little tweak?: `static VALUE
unref(self)  
        VALUE self;
{            
        g_object_unref(_SELF(self));
        return Qnil;
}

... and modified the slideshow code...

newPixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf.new(@filenames.next, 1024, 800)
@image.pixbuf = newPixbuf
newPixbuf.unref`

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to add an "unref" method to Gdk::Pixbuf. This is certainly not possible from within Ruby which I would prefer.

Comment: Just read about this issue on Python FAQ, [Check here](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#8.4). The GC should take care of this but maybe it takes to kick in. A solution may be trying to create a method where the pixbuf has local scope which may then force the GC to deal with it, lets say,  a method called get_image_from_file which in turn returns a Gtk::Image and takes the filename as argument. the pixbuf will be used only locally within that method, this may trick the GC to kick in since we have garbage left to collect. :/

Comment: You were right, the GC should have taken care of it. There is a Glib::Object method .ref_count which is implemented in Ruby and I noticed that by only creating a Pixbuf object its reference count is 2 and not 1, connecting it to an image makes 3 and clearing the image reduces it to 1 and not 0, so the GC doesn't kick in. As I mentioned in my own answer to the question I got rid of this bug by updating my gdk3 Gem. Thanks for your hints, they got me on the right way.